# Modeling Population Growth

Tags: differential-equations

So I have an equation to describe population growth

[image: population growth equation]

where a and b are constants. Typically b is small so that initially, since the population p(t) is small, the squared term can be neglected and the population growth is exponential.

how do I solve the differential equation for p(t) with p(t = 0) = 1 where a = 2 and b = 0.05
and how do I find the value of p(t) as t → ∞

Comment: Is this a math question or a question about how to solve this using Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: This DE is separable so you have $$\frac{dp}{p(a+b p)} = dt $$

Comment: If $p$ has an asymptote, necessarily $ap-bp^2=0$ so either $p=0$ or $p=b/a$.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[p]
p[t_] = p[t] /. 
  DSolve[{p'[t] == 2 p[t] - 0.05 p[t]^2, p[0] == 1}, p, t][[1]]
Plot[p[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]